# How to convert string to equation with List Comprehensions

Tags: python

I want to solve system of equations in python. The first code works as expected but the second doesn't although it looks wery much the same. The second code gives me error: "name 'x' is not defined". I don't understand, why this is not the case in the firs code but in the second is. The aproach in the first code is not general enough for me, because i need this for systems with different number of equations.
Thanks for help!

```
#first code:
eq1 = 'x[0]**2 + x[0]*x[1]-10'
eq2 = 'x[1]+3*x[0]*x[1]**2-57'
def equat(x):
    return [eval(eq1), eval(eq2)]
res = scipy.optimize.root(equat, x0=(0, 0))
res.x
```

```
#second code:
eqn = ['x[0]**2 + x[0]*x[1]-10',
       'x[1]+3*x[0]*x[1]**2-57']
def equat(x):
    return [eval(eqi) for eqi in eqn]
res = scipy.optimize.root(equat, x0=(0, 0))
res.x
```

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval` for this? Why not just define actual `eq1` and `eq2` functions? If you want to iterate over them from a list, you can just... put the functions into a list: `[eq1, eq2]` just as if they were any other kind of object.

Comment: Anyway, the problem isn't (directly) caused by list comprehensions; the problem is caused by the variable scope available to `eval` (okay, I guess it's because of the comprehension that this happens).

Comment: The problem is, that I work on a programme, which need to generate system of equations (constraint equations), depends on user input. So defining it separately is not applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use eval, you shold determine the scope of the variables used. The following code worked:

```
import scipy
from scipy import optimize

#second code:
eqn = ['x[0]**2 + x[0]*x[1]-10',
       'x[1]+3*x[0]*x[1]**2-57']
def equat(x):
    return [eval(eqi, {"x": x}) for eqi in eqn]
res = scipy.optimize.root(equat, x0=(0, 0))
res.x
```

Comment: It looks fine, but here is new problem... in the system I can also have trigonometric functions like:
`eqn = ['x[0]**2 + x[0]*x[1]-10',
            'x[0] + np.sin(x[1])']`
If i put this in your code, the following error occur:
`name 'np' is not defined`

Comment: Have you tried to insert np in the scope list? {"x": x, "np":  np}

Comment: I insert np in a function as you wrote, and now it works. Thanks for help man!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions are objects, and you can store them in lists, etc. as if they were any other kind of object. In particular, you can retrieve them from a list and call the result, regardless of naming.

`eval` is a crude tool that is almost never what you really want to be using in Python.

So, let's build the relevant functions:

```
def eq1(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[0]*x[1] - 10

def eq2(x):
    return x[1] + 3 *x[0]*x[1]**2 - 57
```

And put them in a list:

```
eqns = [eq1, eq2]
```

And use a list comprehension to apply the functions from our main heuristic function:

```
def equat(x):
    return [eqn(x) for eqn in eqns]
```

And do optimization as before:

```
res = scipy.optimize.root(equat, x0=(0, 0))
```